# Passing index to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update a set of elements in my doc using jQuery.

I can't pass the `i` index to the `$.post` callback function.

here is the code

```
function updateValues(){
  val=document.getElementsByName('valueAN');

  for ( i=0; i < val.length; i++ ){
    $.post('',{func:'updateAN',index:i},
      (function(data,status){
        val[i].value = data;
      })(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you just put var in front of i?   ```for(var i = 0; i < val.legnth; i++ ){``` and see if that works?

Comment: the current code just puts 1-8 to the elements - it disregards the return string from server...

Comment: if you are using JQuery, why not use the `$.each` function to loop through your elements?

Comment: ochi - could you show me how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use a closure:

```
function updateValues(){
  val=document.getElementsByName('valueAN');

  for ( i=0; i < val.length; i++ ){
    (function(i){
       $.post('',{func:'updateAN',index:i}, function(data,status){
        val[i].value = data;
       });
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    var val = $("[name=valueAN]");

    function updateValues() {        
      return $.when.apply(val, $.map(val, function(el, i) {
        return $.post("", {"func": "updateAN", "index": i}
        , function(data, status) {
            el.value = data;
        });
      }));          
    };

    updateValues().then(function() {  
      $.each(arguments, function(key, val) {
        console.log(key, val)
      });
      $.each(val, function(i, el) {
        console.log(el.value)
      })
    });
```

```js
var val = $("[name=valueAN]");

function updateValues() {

  return $.when.apply(val, $.map(val, function(el, key) {
    return $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/6a76aa9d2921350c9d53/raw/49fbc054731540fa68b565e398d3574fde7366e9/abc.txt"
                   , {func:"updateAN"}
                   , function(data, status) {
      el.value = data;
    });
  }));
  
};

updateValues().then(function() {  
  $.each(arguments, function(key, val) {
    console.log(key, val)
  });
  $.each(val, function(i, el) {
    console.log(el.value)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="valueAN" value="" />
<input type="text" name="valueAN" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a clousure, but you are leaving `i` behind.

#### If you are using jQuery:

```
    function updateValues(){
    $("valueAN").each(function(i) {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/",
           data: {func:'updateAN',index:i},
              success: function(data){
                  $(this).val(data);
              }
        });
    });
}
```

If you are using pure Javascript then you should follow @Yukulélé answer, in your case `i` will always be passed with the value of `val.length-1` to the function, and you will do the `$post` ajax call with the same args `i` times.

Answer (score 0):

You use `i` inside a callback function for `$.post()`. By the time this callback function is executed, the `for` loop is already way done, so `i` is at the last value it was on. This is one of the things that can be confusing about asynchronous code.

In the end, it means that inside callback functions you can't rely on variables external from the callback function.

You can either use a closure like @Yukulélé suggests, or use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a custom callback function for each `$.post()` callback, but be sure to check the [browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) before you're going that way.